# Finding the Jacobian of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following script in matlab and the goal is to compute the jacobian of `$f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$` which should give me a 4 by 4 matrix but instead I get a 7 by 4$ matrix. I am unsure what is wrong with this code it should work.

```
syms m M L J p_x p_theta theta X g K_m K_g r V_in R_m;
h= (m+M)*(m*L^2/4+J) - (m*L/2 * cos(theta))^2;
f_1 = [1/h * [ (m*L^2/4+J)*p_x + m*L/2 cos(theta)* p_theta]];
f_2 = [1/h * [ (m*L/2 * cos(theta))*p_x + (m+M)*p_theta]];
F = K_m *K_g/r *[ (V_in -K_m*K_g * f_1/r)/R_m];
f_3 = F;
f_4 = m*L/2 *sin (theta)*(f_1*f_2+g);
J_1=jacobian([f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4],[X;theta;p_x;p_theta]);
subs(J_1,[X,theta,p_x,p_theta],[0,0,0,0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can see is that you missed an operator in defining `f_1`. Did you mean it to be a 1x2 array? If not, I'd suggest something like the following (I inserted a `*` between `L/2` and `cos(theta)`):

```
f_1 = [1/h * [ (m*L^2/4+J)*p_x + m*L/2 * cos(theta)* p_theta]];
```

This will give a 4x4 matrix for the final answer, as you desire.